# Add Element to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, addition

I´m pretty new to coding. I have a method "einkaufen" where the user is asked to chose a Product. For each choice there is a switch case that asks if he wants to buy the product. If the user types "ja", I want to add the item´s price to an ArrayList "einkaufsliste" I created in the beginning.

But Eclipse is giving me an Error that says "einkaufsliste cannot be resolved".

How can I fix this?

```
//List with prices:
double [] waren = new double[5];
        waren[0] = 0.00;
        waren[1] = 2.49;
        waren[2] = 2.79;
        waren[3] = 0.79;
        waren[4] = 2.99;

//List to add to:
ArrayList<Double>einkaufsliste = new ArrayList<Double>();
        einkaufsliste.add(0.00);   **//right here i can eaysily add a value to the list**

//Method:
public static void einkaufen(double waren[]) {

        int n;
        String kaufen = "ja", x;
        boolean wareKaufen = true, wareNichtKaufen = false;

        System.out.println("Welche der angebotenen Waren möchtest du kaufen?");
        System.out.println("Angebot: \t1: Kinderriegel");
        System.out.println("Angebot: \t2: Nutella");
        System.out.println("Angebot: \t3: Wasser");
        System.out.println("Angebot: \t4: CDs");

        Scanner nutzerWare = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = nutzerWare.nextInt();

        switch (n) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Deine Auswahl: Kinderriegel \tPreis: " + waren[n] + "\nMöchtst du diese Ware zu deinem Einkaufswagen hinzufügen?");
            Scanner kinderriegelKaufen = new Scanner(System.in);
            x = kinderriegelKaufen.nextLine();
            if(x.equals(kaufen)) {
                wareKaufen=true;
                System.out.println(wareKaufen);             
                einkaufsliste.add(waren[n]);    **//ERROR right here I want to add the Item to the List but it´s not working**
                } else {
                    wareKaufen = false;
                    System.out.println(wareNichtKaufen);    
                }
            break;
```

Comment: The `einkaufen` method is static, and it cannot access `einkaufsliste` without either a reference to its declaring class, or a direct reference to it (the latter is preferred, just like you did for the `waren` parameter).

Comment: @fluffy I´m not sure what I did different for `waren` and @Matteo if I add static, it says "Illegal modifier, only final is permitted"..

Comment: @Matteo unfortunately still not working with `static final`. If i put only the `final`, without the `static` it´s fine but then it´s again the problem that I can´t use it in my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Problem had to do with the `static` and I couldn´t simply add a `static` infront of my ArrayList, I simply deleted the List from the main method and created it outside of any method. Not sure if it´s the right way, but for now it works. Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

BTW. You can change your `switch` statement to a simple `if` stamement, because you have only 1 given case so there is no really need to do a `switch case`.

***Like this:***

```
        if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println("Deine Auswahl: Kinderriegel \tPreis: " + waren[n] + "\nMöchtst du diese Ware zu deinem Einkaufswagen hinzufügen?");
        Scanner kinderriegelKaufen = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = kinderriegelKaufen.nextLine();
        if (x.equals(kaufen)) {
            wareKaufen = true;
            System.out.println(wareKaufen);
            einkaufsliste.add(waren[n]);
        } else {
            wareKaufen = false;
            System.out.println(wareNichtKaufen);
        }
    }
```

***Full Code with `switch` here:***

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    double[] waren = new double[5];
    waren[0] = 0.00;
    waren[1] = 2.49;
    waren[2] = 2.79;
    waren[3] = 0.79;
    waren[4] = 2.99;


    einkaufen(waren);


}


//Method:
public static void einkaufen(double waren[]) {

    ArrayList<Double> einkaufsliste = new ArrayList<Double>();
    einkaufsliste.add(0.00);

    int n;
    String kaufen = "ja", x;
    boolean wareKaufen = true, wareNichtKaufen = false;

    System.out.println("Welche der angebotenen Waren möchtest du kaufen?");
    System.out.println("Angebot: \t1: Kinderriegel");
    System.out.println("Angebot: \t2: Nutella");
    System.out.println("Angebot: \t3: Wasser");
    System.out.println("Angebot: \t4: CDs");

    Scanner nutzerWare = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = nutzerWare.nextInt();

    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Deine Auswahl: Kinderriegel \tPreis: " + waren[n] + "\nMöchtst du diese Ware zu deinem Einkaufswagen hinzufügen?");
            Scanner kinderriegelKaufen = new Scanner(System.in);
            x = kinderriegelKaufen.nextLine();
            if (x.equals(kaufen)) {
                wareKaufen = true;
                System.out.println(wareKaufen);
                einkaufsliste.add(waren[n]);
            } else {
                wareKaufen = false;
                System.out.println(wareNichtKaufen);
            }
            break;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it with `if` before, but struggled, that´s why I used the `switch`. Probably gonna replace it :)

Comment: Gern geschehen :)